# Sql поиск по базе данных по совпадению с условием

Tags: mysql

В базе данных, поле filter может содержать например такие значения:

```
Цвет:Белый,Цвет:Желтый,Размер:1,Размер:2,Размер:3,Размер:5
```

Можно ли как-то сделать выборку не просто перечислив все условия:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE filter LIKE '%Размер:3%' OR '%Размер:4%' OR '%Размер:5%'
```

а что-то типа:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE filter LIKE '%Размер:(>=3 && <=5)%'
```

Comment: Укажите пожалуйста по каким причинам вы не сделали поля Цвет и Размер и храните все в одном поле?

Comment: @becouse так работает движок. Фильтров очень много может быть, для каждого создавать отдельное поле не вариант.

Comment: Я не об этом. У вас есть товар. У него характеристики. Вы сделали нерабочий вариант вместо третьей нормальной формы. Что мешает хранить характеристики как поля? У вас допустим таблица с полями Название, Цвет и Размер. Поле фильтр это, например JSON. Читаете его и применяете к полям.

Comment: Для каждой записи разумно хранить набор фильтров в отдельной таблице

Comment: В MySQL есть регулярные выражения. http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Regexp.html но это сводит на нет весь смысл использовать реляционную БД. Лучше уж в текстовом файле храните

Comment: @becouse спасибо, последний ответ помог.